# DB structure to store OAUTH access credentials

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, twitter, oauth, oauth-2.0

is it possible to store all the OAUTH token details that received from various providers like Twitter and Facebook in the same table. Because in case of Facebook, we are receiving only `access_token` to access his details but when comes to twitter we are receiving two values `oauth_token` and `oauth_token_secret`. And i don't know about Google api.

Do i need to create separate table for each OAUTH provider? So what is the optimal way to store this in DB or do we have create separate table for each provider? Sorry if my understanding is wrong, and please correct me if so.